# Java Inheritance, Dynamic Dispatch Exam Question

Tags: java, inheritance

This is a question from UW CSE 143. I am just studying past exams to get better at Java.

```
    public class Box extends Pill {

        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("Box 2");
        }

        public void method3() {
            method2();
            System.out.println("Box 3");
        }

    }

    public class Cup extends Box {

        public void method1() {
            System.out.println("Cup 1");
        }

        public void method2() {
            System.out.println("Cup 2");
            super.method2();
        }

    }

    Box var3 = new Cup();
```

Question:
What is the outprint if `var3.method3()` is called?

I have no idea why the answer is
Cup 2/Box 2/Box 3

Where is cup 2 from?  I get the dynamic type is Cup. But if Cup class does not have method3, so it goes to the parent class for method3.

Comment: Please format the source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var3.method3()
```

executes the `Box` method (since `Cup` doesn't override that method):

```
public void method3() {
    method2();
    System.out.println("Box 3");
}
```

`method2()` executes `Cup`'s `method2()`, since the dynamic type of `var3` is `Cup`, and `Cup` overrides `method2()` of `Box`:

```
public void method2() {
    System.out.println("Cup 2");
    super.method2();
}
```

This prints "Cup 2" and then `super.method2()` executes the super class method:

```
public void method2() {
    System.out.println("Box 2");
}
```

This prints "Box 2".

Finally, when we return to `method3()`, "Box 3" is printed.

Hence the output is

```
Cup 2
Box 2
Box 3.
```

Comment: Yeah I am just surprised that method2() executes Cup's method2() because it is inside the box class.